# Creating dataframe under reactive values

Tags: r, shiny

Not sure what is wrong with the below code, when I try to change the changes the values in "Change to" section the table is not getting updated.Is there way to change the table as we changes the text in "Change to"? Can anyone guide me on this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3"),
               uiOutput("book6")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")
             )
           )))
#server.r
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  
  
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })
  
  output$book3<-renderUI({
    selectInput("bk3", "Label",  choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  })
  
  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to", value=NULL)
  })
  
  df_reactive <- reactiveValues()
  
  rt4 <- reactive({
    df_reactive$DF <- data.frame(
      Test=paste(1:input$text2),
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    if(!is.null(input$bk6) && input$bk6!=""){
      df_reactive$DF[df_reactive$DF$Label==isolate(input$bk3), "Label"] <- input$bk6
    }
    {
      df_reactive$DF
    }
    
  })
  
  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    rt4(),
    rownames= FALSE
    
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please describe how do you want the application to behave. Currently it's not exactly clear. Do you want to have an option to change any value in the column "Label"? I would suggest checking this link, part 2.4 https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit unclear to me, but I think the problem has to do with changing your `reactiveValues` within the `reactive` expression.

It would seem that setting `df_reactive$DF` the first time, will trigger the `rt4()`, as well as when it is called again in changing "Label". It would seem `rt4()` would run over and over repeatedly.

Try using a temporary variable to develop your data.frame the way you'd like, and then set `df_reactive$DF` in the end (and returned in `rt4()`):

```
  rt4 <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(
      Test=paste(1:input$text2),
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    if(!is.null(input$bk6) && input$bk6!=""){
      df[df$Label==isolate(input$bk3), "Label"] <- input$bk6
    } else {
      df
    }
    df_reactive$DF <- df
  })
```

Note: depending on your goals, you may want to use `eventReactive` and make other modifications (do you need `df_reactive$DF` at all?), so that changes are only made in certain conditions (such as input changes) - and not your `reactiveValues` (or use `isolate`).